# Create Array From Current Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is the result of array after i build it using array_push function from mssql result.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [STICKER] => FALCON
            [MONTH] => 1
            [JUM] => 65826210.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [STICKER] => FALCON
            [MONTH] => 2
            [JUM] => 68070573.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [STICKER] => FALCON
            [MONTH] => 3
            [JUM] => 99053067.60
        )

    [3] => 
    [4] => Array
        (
            [STICKER] => HRD
            [MONTH] => 2
            [JUM] => 1521400.00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [STICKER] => HRD
            [MONTH] => 3
            [JUM] => 2093200.00
        )
)
```

I need to convert array above into this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FALCON
            [1] => 65826210.00
            [2] => 68070573.00
            [3] => 99053067.60
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => HRD
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1521400.00
            [3] => 2093200.00
        )
)
```

**Note:**
`Array[0]` values would be 1,2,3 (this is actualy month, i just input up to 3 in order to get the code not too long. but it will be up to 12 (Jan - Dec)).

If from original array, there is none value (example from `array[3]`), then it will be convert to new `array[2]->[1]` with value 0.

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Thanks all!.

Comment: Have you tried any code yet to do this which we can look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this
not the issue with the empty array i could not understand how the program would know that it is STICKER HRD so it will be filled with zero.But you could later check if every month "isset" and if it is not act as it is zero

```
$arr1=array(
 array('STICKER'=>'FALCON','MONTH'=>1,'JUM'=>65826210.00),
 array('STICKER'=>'FALCON','MONTH'=>2,'JUM'=>68070573.00),
 array('STICKER'=>'FALCON','MONTH'=>3,'JUM'=>99053067.60),
 array(),
 array('STICKER'=>'HRD','MONTH'=>2,'JUM'=>1521400.00),
 array('STICKER'=>'HRD','MONTH'=>3,'JUM'=>2093200.00),
);

$arr2=array();
$arr3=array();

$arr2[0][0]="";
foreach($arr1 as $key => $val){
 if(!empty($val)){
    $arr2[0][$val['MONTH']]=$val['MONTH'];

    //group each STICKER
    $arr3[$val['STICKER']][]=$val['JUM'];
 }
}

//transfer the grouped data to arr2
foreach($arr3 as $key => $val){

 $tmp_arr=array($key);

  $arr2[]=array_merge($tmp_arr,$val);
}


print_r($arr2);
```

Comment: thx @knets, your code is actually works. I already modified code to build original array in order to get the result i wanted. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

> If any `month` is not mentioned from `stickers` the `jum` considered as `0`,

```
$array = array(
    array('STICKER' => 'FALCON', 'MONTH' => 1, 'JUM' => 65826210.00),
    array('STICKER' => 'FALCON', 'MONTH' => 2, 'JUM' => 68070573.00),
    array('STICKER' => 'FALCON', 'MONTH' => 3, 'JUM' => 99053067.60),
    array(),
    array('STICKER' => 'HRD', 'MONTH' => 2, 'JUM' => 1521400.00),
    array('STICKER' => 'HRD', 'MONTH' => 3, 'JUM' => 2093200.00),
);

$result[0][] = '';

foreach ($array as $key => $res) {
    if (!empty($res)) {
        $result[0][$res['MONTH']] = $res['MONTH'];
        $result1[$res['STICKER']][$res['MONTH']] = $res['JUM'];
    }
}
foreach ($result1 as $key => $res) {
    $fin = array();
    foreach ($res as $key1 => $re) {
        foreach ($result[0] as $key2 => $month) {
            if ($month != '') {
                if (array_key_exists($month, $res)) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($month, $fin) && $month == $key1) {
                        $fin[$month] = $re;
                    }
                } else {
                    $fin[$month] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $result[] = array_merge(array($key), $fin);
}
echo'<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo'<pre>';
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FALCON
            [1] => 65826210
            [2] => 68070573
            [3] => 99053067.6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => HRD
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1521400
            [3] => 2093200
        )

)
```

I hope this is used to achieve your output(you mentioned in above question)!!